# Can I use Atomikos with Apache DBCP

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, connection-pooling, jta

As the name suggests, can I use Atomikos JTA Transaction Manager with Apache DBCP? 
If so, how should I configure it? I'm using Spring & Hibernate. 
I'm trying to switch to JTA for transaction management.

Comment: check if [this](http://lafernando.com/2011/01/05/xa-transactions-with-apache-dbcp/) helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it.  Atomikos provides a wrapper data source that should be used to wrap the DBCP dataSource. Your database & jdbc driver should support XA.

And then the usual spring configuration to setup a jta transaction manager.

This link has the detailed instructions and configuration.
http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration